# Creating array of objects only does 1 iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I'm trying to create a variable array of objects however when I try to do a for loop it only does the iteration once and then stops.

```
function generate() {
        works = [];  // Clear array
        console.log(num.value);
        for(i=0; i < num.value; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            var fire = new Firework(cxt);
            works.push(fire);
        }
    }
```

Where cxt is a html canvas context and num.value is a range.

This will only do one iteration and then stop. Here is the constructor for the firework object.

```
function Firework(Context, DestX, DestY, Speed, Radius, Color, Scale) {
    // Basic Stuff
    this.stat = 0;  // Status of explosion 0 - 100
    this.speed = Speed || 5;
    this.color = Color || "blue";
    this.radius = Radius || 5;
    this.scale = Scale || 1;

    // Movment Stuff
    this.curX = 0;
    this.curY = 0;
    this.destX = DestX || 100;
    this.destY = DestY || 100;
    this.dX = this.speed * Math.cos(Math.atan((this.destY)/(this.destX)));
    this.dY = this.speed * Math.sin(Math.atan((this.destY)/(this.destX)));

    // Spark Stuff
    this.sparkNum = 100;  // SNumber of sparks per level
    this.sparkLvls = 4;  // Number of levels of sparks
    this.sparkAngle = [];
    this.sparkDist = [];

    // Setup Angles and Distances
    for(i=0; i<this.sparkLvls; i++) {  // 4 Levels of sparks
        this.sparkAngle[i] = [];
        this.sparkDist[i] = new Array(this.sparkNum);
        this.sparkDist[i].fill(i*this.radius);  // Set Distance init to 0

        // Generate angles of sparks randomly
        for(j=0; j<this.sparkNum; j++) {
            this.sparkAngle[i][j] = Math.random()*2*Math.PI;
        }
        this.sparkAngle[i].sort();  // Sort angles for difference calc

        // Store Angles as differences between them
        var temp = [];
        for(j=1; j<this.sparkNum; j++) {
            temp[j] = this.sparkAngle[i][j] - this.sparkAngle[i][j-1];
        }
        this.sparkAngle[i] = temp;
    }

    this.context = Context;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks ahead of time

Comment: num.value is the current position of a range on an html doc. I also checked t o make sure it is greater than 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use same variable `i` (without var  is a global variable )

add var within the for loops

```
for(var i=0; i < num.value; i++) { // in  generate function

for(var i=0; i<this.sparkLvls; i++) {  // in Firework function
```